# How to make blocks Outerwear, Rompers, Costumes and Dresses fixed using Grid CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to make blocks Outerwear, Rompers, Costumes and Dresses fixed using Grid CSS?

If one scrolls the page, these blocks should go up or down with the same proportions (fractions).

How to make it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Качественная детская одежда</title>
    <style>
      .wrapper{
        display:grid;
        /*grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1 fr;*/
    grid-template-columns:repeat(4, 2fr);   
    grid-column-gap:1.5em;   
        grid-row-gap:0.5em;
        /*grid-gap:1em;*/  
      }
      .wrapper > div{
        background:#F0FFF0;
        padding:1em;
        font-family:'Bahnschrift', Light, semicondensed;  
        /*font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;*/     
      }
      .wrapper > div:nth-child(odd){
        background:#F0FFFF;
      }
    </style>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="tel"><img src="images/WhatsApp_chatting.jpg" width="60" alt="Whats App"><font size="6" color="mediumspringgreen"> Tel number</font></div>
      <div><center><strong>OUTERWEAR</strong></center></div>
      <div><center><strong>ROMPERS</strong></center></div>
      <div><center><strong>COSTUMES</strong></center></div>
      <div><center><strong>DRESSES</strong></center></div>
      <div>Комплект пуховой для девочек "Адриана"</div>
      <div>Комбинезон для девочки</div>
      <div>Костюм тройка для девочки: шорты, майка и блузка</div>
      <div>Платье розовое в полоску</div>
    </div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grid-tmeplate-areas` on the ***parent*** and `grid-area` on the ***children*** to place the layout of the sections that you want. As for having the four elements on top, make them ***auto*** using `grid-termplate-rows` so the row will auto adjust to that rows highest height content block.

I moved the content matching the header sections into the header sections div wrapper and also added a class for styling those header sections. This helps to keep the layout a bit more cohesive for products, placing the description of the product within the same div. Also added a main reset for padding, margin and box-sizing as well.

```css
body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Bahnschrift', Light, semicondensed;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(calc(100vh - 4em) max-content);
  grid-column-gap: 1.5em;
  grid-row-gap: .5em;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "tel outerwear rompers costumes dresses" 
     "main-cont main-cont main-cont main-cont main-cont";
  width: minmax(360px calc(100vw - 2rem))
  height: auto; 
  padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper>.sect {
  background: #F0FFF0;
  padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper>.sect:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F0FFFF;
}

.tel {
  grid-area: tel;
}

.outerwear {
  grid-area: outerwear;
}

.rompers {
  grid-area: rompers;
}

.costumes {
  grid-area: costumes;
}

.dresses {
  grid-area: dresses;
}

.main-cont {
  grid-area: main-cont;
  padding: 2rem;
  background:  #F0FFFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tel"><img src="images/WhatsApp_chatting.jpg" width="60" alt="Whats App">
      <font size="6" color="mediumspringgreen"> Tel number</font>
    </div>
    <div class="outerwear sect">
      <h4>OUTERWEAR</h4>
      <p class="outerwear-cont">Комплект пуховой для девочек "Адриана"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rompers sect">
      <h4>ROMPERS</h4>
      <p class="rompers-cont">Комбинезон для девочки</p>
    </div>
    <div class="costumes sect">
      <h4>COSTUMES</h4>
      <p class="costumes-cont">Костюм тройка для девочки: шорты, майка и блузка</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dress sect">
      <h4>DRESSES</h4>
      <p class="dresses-cont">Платье розовое в полоску</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-cont">"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
      assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus,
      ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."</div>
  </div>
</body>
```